# Calendar + Events in Drupal 5

Tags: events, drupal, content-management-system, calendar, view

"**Events**" module introduces Event content type, which has such two fields as event_start and event_end. While "Events" module has own calendar, I am need a few different calendars - so I chose *Calendar* module - which is based on *Views*.

And here goes the problem: I create a new View, select **View Type = Calendar**,
in **Fields** section listbox I am able to see and add "Event:Start Time" and "Event: End Time"
field, but still when saving my Calendar view I get this red message:

> 

```
* The Calendar View requires at least one date field.
* The Calendar requires as arguments Calendar: Year, Calendar: Month, and Calendar: Day, or Calendar: Year and Calendar: Week
```

In other words, "Event:Start Time" is not seen as date field.

Is this a known Calendar+Events bug in Drupal 5 (which I have to use). 
Is Events module deprecated/troublesome and better be replaced with CCK+Views?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've found at [Calendar official page](http://drupal.org/project/calendar)

> Event module event fields are no longer supported. The Event module has its own calendar that you can use to display Event fields.

Apparently, Calendar users should stick to CCK+Date